# Create a view like Hindu Calendar view

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, tablelayout, calendarview

I have been programming for a quite a while in iOS, however i am still a newbie in android. I want to create a layout something similar to image show here.

[image]

This is a Hindu calendar app and I want to create a UI something similar to this.

I have few questions regarding how I can design it in Android.

1. Should I use the CalendarView. Does CalendarView provide this level of UI customisation. If yes then any link regarding how to do it will be useful for me.
2. I have tried using GridView. However I am not sure how to set width of the first column smaller than other columns. Any help on this would be great.
3. I have also thought of using TabletLayout but I am not sure how useful will it be.
4. If any other better approach...

I just need a head start on this so any help regarding this would be of great help for me.

Awaiting for help.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say a `TableLayout` will work the best for this layout, with `TableLayout` you can adjust the width of each column as you like, here is a link to official documentation :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Comment: Thanks Brooks for the help. I guess then I will start with a TableLayout implementation. :)